# How to transfer 1:1 nft to wallet

Tags: nft, erc-721, opensea

Soon our team will release an nft project with legendary characters. One of these characters will need to be sent to the collaborator's wallet. What are the ways to do this? Any suggestions worth their weight in gold

Answer (score 1):

A Merkle Drop is pretty efficient to distribute NFTs to a defined list of users without having a deployment cost proportional to the size of the list.

https://blog.openzeppelin.com/workshop-recap-building-an-nft-merkle-drop/